# How to show hamburger menu only on mobile-Angular?

Tags: angular, toggle, hamburger-menu

I have a regular navbar on larger screens. I want to have a hamburger menu only on mobile devices  and the menu icon only to be shown on mobile. I want to achieve that with Angular(I am beginner). How do I do that , don't want  to use Angular material. Here is my code.

```
<div class="b-navbar">
    <div class="b-navbar__toggle">
      <button (click)="onToggle()" class="b-navbar__button">
        <fa-icon [icon]="hamburgerBars" class="b-navbar__icon"></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <ul class="b-navbar__nav" *ngIf="showToggle">
      <li class="b-navbar__nav">
        <a routerLink="/home" class="b-navbar__link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-navbar__nav">
        <a class="b-navbar__link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-navbar__nav">
        <a routerLink="/about" class="b-navbar__link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-navbar__nav">
        <a class="b-navbar__link" href="#">Reviews</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-navbar__nav">
        <a class="b-navbar__link" href="#">Locations</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-navbar__nav">
        <a routerLink="/contact" class="b-navbar__link">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Angular Code`

```
hamburgerBars = faBars;
onToggle() {
    this.showToggle = !this.showToggle;
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoQ6S1a32j8&list=PLL5EufAChQoXvMXX-GY72rFQBmDnMmWSZ&index=9

Please check this video, she used scss, and she is show the hamburger in mobile and hide in desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display something in small screens only, you can use media queries in CSS.

```
.hamburger {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Here is the final solution in [Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k8ydcv?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: When I do that the whole navbar is gone , it is not even displaying in the large sizes. What to do?

Comment: Add other styles for normal size

Comment: When i do that the whole navmenu disappears on large screen ,not only the hamburger icon.

Comment: give me the example. because the update include that problem too

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/vXkYNJeMzkNPW75t5PkQKF Here is the css code

Comment: Still can not see the code come to : https://www.linkedin.com/in/hojjatollah-bakhtiyari-kiya-391009100/

Comment: I send you a connection on linkedin

Answer (score 3):

Generally, using media-querys is better the aproach: "Mobile first, then adjust the design for larger devices"

```
.b-navbar__nav { //by defect not show
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { //when larger screen
  .b-navbar__nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
```